# Why do ephemeral segments get smaller with an increase in logical CPUs?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm currently reading up a little about garbage collection in .NET and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) Microsoft article about it. My question is about the section [Ephemeral generations and segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#ephemeral-generations-and-segments). There is this table:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╦════════╦════════╗
║                                 ║ 32-bit ║ 64-bit ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ Workstation GC                  ║ 16 MB  ║ 256 MB ║
║ Server GC                       ║ 64 MB  ║ 4 GB   ║
║ Server GC with > 4 logical CPUs ║ 32 MB  ║ 2 GB   ║
║ Server GC with > 8 logical CPUs ║ 16 MB  ║ 1 GB   ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Now what I don't understand is why the size of an ephemeral segment decreases with a higher logical CPU count, can anyone explain?

P.S if this question better suits the Software Engineering SE or any other please let me know so I can move it there

Comment: In server GC mode there is one GC thread per logical CPU, increasing the size of gen0 and gen1 can cause a memory overuse

Answer (score 0):

Because in Server GC the number of Managed Heaps is equal to the number of logical CPUs.